Is it possible that cursor changes color when hovering image?
I changed standard cursor to grab. What i would like in addition is that cursor (grab) changes color, not background.
Here is a part from javascript. I manage with "grab" but not with color change. Any advice?
x.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    // Change the button's background color
    

    x.style.cursor = "grab";
    
    x.style.Color = "red"


  });


color, not Color.

the style property is color and not Color

thanks, that is what i wanted to confirm, not possible, ony URL.

Oh, I thought my interpretation of the question was wrong, that's why I removed the comment. You could rephrase the question to more clearly explain your goal, which seems to be "I want to change the color of the cursor".

You can assign a custom image as the cursor when hovering over the button.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lipsum</title>
  <style>
    button:hover {
      cursor: url('https://i.sstatic.net/265RWKkM.png'), grab;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button>Foo</button>
</body>

</html>




Supported image file formats

I think that it is possible to make svg images with different colors and connect them with the colors that are needed, an example of connecting svg is at the link.
MDN Web/CSS/cursor
body {
      cursor: url('path-to-image.png'), url('path-to-image-2.svg'), url('path-to-image-3.jpeg'), auto;
}


How would this answer the actual issue? OP only wants to change the cursor('s color) when hovering over a certain element

@DarkBee I believe that this is impossible, so I offer an alternative

How would that be impossible then?

@DarkBee if you know how to do it, just write the answer to this question

Sure, but don't make statements that are incorrect

I did not draw a conclusion, I shared my opinion
